# SQL using subquery table multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to pull data from table t

```
 select 
 (select round(avg(High),2) from t where  High!=0)as High,
 (select round(avg(Med),2) from t where Med!=0) as Med,
  (select round(avg(Low),2) from t where  Low!=0) as Low
```

and my table t is

```
    select AAAA as High, BBBB as Med, CCCC as Low from TABLE1 where company like '%3m%'
  union all
  select  
  (select round(XXX,2) from TABLE2 where company like '%3m%' and XXX!=0)as High,
 (select round(YYY),2) from TABLE2 where company like '%3m%' and YYY!=0) as Med,
 (select round(ZZZ,2) from TABLE2 where company like '%3m%' and ZZZ!=0) as Low
```

i wonder how i can use a query to pull data from table t without using subquery repetitively (originally I don't have t)?
what I'm really trying to do is to get average from two rows where one row is not zero 
Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Reading only the subject line, sql server has the keyword, "with" which is the cat's meow for these situations.

Comment: that's right, I only need "with", sorry I didn't realize previously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query. It uses the CASE function. If the condition is not satisfied, then the value is assumed to be NULL, so that it would not be counted in the average.

Since you do not have t to start with, you can create it using a CTE.

```
    WITH t as
    (
     select AAAA as High, BBBB as Med, CCCC as Low from TABLE1 where company like '%3m%'
      union all
      select  
      (select round(XXX,2) from TABLE2 where company like '%3m%' and XXX!=0)as High,
     (select round(YYY),2) from TABLE2 where company like '%3m%' and YYY!=0) as Med,
     (select round(ZZZ,2) from TABLE2 where company like '%3m%' and ZZZ!=0) as Low
    )
SELECT 
ROUND(AVG(case when company like '%3m%'and ABC <> 0 then High else null end), 2) High,
ROUND(AVG(case when company like '%3m%'and DEF <> 0 then Medium else null end), 2) Medium,
ROUND(AVG(case when company like '%3m%'and GHI <> 0 then Low else null end), 2) Low
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks, with t as is what I want! Sorry I wrongly put company like '%3m%' and XXX!=0 in my early post

Comment: No problem. If you filter out zero's and check the company name in the CTE (you have to do it for TABLE1 too), then actually you would not have to repeat it in the final SELECT. Also, you are rounding the values two times, which might lead to some errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can not because every of the subqueries is different -in the filter condition.

Comment: sorry I wrote wrong im my query. what I'm really trying to do is to get average from two rows where one row is not zero

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can:

```
select
    round(SUM(case when High<>0 then High else 0 end)/SUM(case when High<>0 then 1 else 0 end),2) as High,
    round(SUM(case when Med<>0 then Med else 0 end)/SUM(case when Med<>0 then 1 else 0 end),2) as Med,
    round(SUM(case when Low<>0 then Low else 0 end)/SUM(case when Low<>0 then 1 else 0 end),2) as Low
from
  (
    select AAAA as High, BBBB as Med, CCCC as Low from TABLE1 where company like '%3m%'
    union all
    select round(XXX,2) High, round(YYY,2) Med, round(ZZZ,2) Low from TABLE2 where company like '%3m%'
  )
```

Comment: sorry, i don't have t originally, do I have to create t first then delete t?